# Determine first and last qualifying records for each date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to find the first and last of each unique day (column A) that qualifies (column B).

In column C I need to write "first" or "last".

```
A     B    C
date  use  result
-----------------
1-1   yes  last
2-1   no
2-1   yes  first
2-1   no
2-1   yes
2-1   yes  last
2-1   no  
3-1   no
3-1   yes  first
```

The dates are sorted.  If only a single date record qualifies (such as 1-1 or 3-1 in this example), it can be labeled either "first" or "last", whichever is simplest for the approach taken; the label choice isn't important in that situation (although a label is required for the qualifying record, as in the case of 3-1).

Suggestions for an approach?

Comment: Is your data sorted by dates?

Comment: good point, yes sorted by date

Comment: Why is 1-1 "last" instead of "first", and 3-1 "first" instead of "last"?  What is your rule for single qualifying dates?

Comment: again good point, single qualifying dates can be labeled either first or last, either is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula to calculate it:
`=IF(B2="yes",IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$B$1:B1,"yes")=0,"first",IF(COUNTIFS(A3:$A$10000,A2,B3:$B$10000,"yes")=0,"last","")),"")`

It seems complicated, but it very simply does what you've explained:

- if column B of the row contains "yes", then

  - checks whether actual row is the first one of the same day with "yes"

    - if yes then gives "first" *(if a day has only one qualifying row, it'll be first)*
    - else checks whether actual row is the last one of the same day with "yes"

      - if yes, then gives "last"
      - if no, then leave cell blank
  - else (if column B is "no") leaves cell blank

The formula currently works only up to 10,000 rows, if you have more, simply increase the numbers in it.

[image]

Comment: wonderful, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.